# Cant identify part even if it has numbers on it

Tags: components, identification, datasheet

i have this part but i cant find any datasheet about it or what it is , or what can i use for replacement

To me it seems DS3907 HY1MG1  but nothing on the internet not even related

Here is a full image:

[image]

Here is the board:
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: Its an electric pump with battery as well . here a gallery of pictures after it was repaired by someone https://imgur.com/a/UhLjLnp

Comment: Here the product page http://spectrababy.co.kr/shop/shopdetail.html?branduid=439610&xcode=002&mcode=004&scode=&type=X&search=&sort=order

Answer (score 3):

@Chupacabras is correct in his assessment that this is a MOSFET.

Specifically it is a 30-V rated P-Channel MOSFET in a SOP-8 package. The full part number is [GSMDS3907](http://www.gs-power.com/db/pictures/modules/PDT/PDT060207001/DS_GSMDS3907_Rev1.3.pdf), manufactured by Globaltech Semiconductor.

[image: Pinout]

[image: Marking Info]

<sup>Credit to "www.chip.tomsk.ru" for listing the part number with its marking</sup>

Comment: Nice! How did you find it?

Comment: @GlennWillen I googled DS3907 SOP8 MOSFET. Found some random Russian page that expanded the part number.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your board, how the chip is connected.
3 pins are connected together and other 4 pins are connected together. This is the way how a mosfet is usually connected.

There is a diode and a inductor connected to one group of those pins. So 99.9% probability it is a transistor (most likely mosfet).

Comment: Thank you for the information . I tried to find that on the internet and aside the russian page and PDF nothing else . What can i use as a replacement for that ?